# CommunicationChannel faulted - DTexec vs. SQL Job Agent

Tags: wcf, channel, faulted, dtexec

I have a SSIS package with a Script task in it.
In the script I use IRequestChannel to communicate with SAP RFC programme.

Weird error is, that if I run the package via dtexec, I get the error message that my channel is in a faulted state and the script terminates.
I tried all the error checking routines found here or on MSDN like

```
if (channel.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
{
   // abort channel and create new one
}
```

but the error still exists.

However, if I run the same SSIS package via Job Agent in our SQL server 2008, it runs perfectly fine without any message that the channel is faulted.

How can that be?
Thanks for any explanations.
Chris